# Optimal data structure for a table

Tags: data-structures, sparse-matrix, tabular

Our team is working on implementation of the table widget for mobile platform (one of the application is mobile office like MS Excel).

We need to optimize the data structure for storing table data (the simple 2-d array is used).

Could you, please, suggest the optimal data structure for storing table data. Below are some of requirements for the data structure:

- the size of the table can be up to 2^32 x 2^32;
- majority of table cells are empty (i.e. the table is sparse), so is is desirable not to store data for empty cells;
- interface of the data structure should support inserting/removing rows and columns;
- data structure should allow to iterate through non-empty cells in forward and backward direction;
- cells of the table can be merged (i.e. one cell can span more than one row and/or column).

Comment: Would a binary search tree (with key=y*2^32+x) work? With such a tree, merging doesn't look terribly complicated either.

Comment: I'm hesitating about binary search tree, because I need to store indices for each cell. And when row or column is inseted or removed, I have to update all indices.

Comment: If you have a tree of rows, each of which is a tree, you can avoid updating row indices in every cell by updating them in the table of rows only. I don't think you can find a data structure where you wouldn't need to either move cell data or update indices on row/col insertion/deletion. I would also be surprised to see a really large table directly editable by the user on a mobile device for 2 reasons: there isn't much memory on such devices and writing or editing stuff isn't very convenient on them. I don't think the mobile version of the problem is big enough for index updating to matter.

Comment: If I'm wrong about the scale of the problem, please add more data to the question.

Comment: Maybe there exists some implementation of sparse matrix data structure which allows to insert/remove rows and columns? 

Or, for example, some variations of Dancing Links (DLX) data structure suggested by D.E. Knuth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking more about the problem with the row/column insertion/deletion, I've come up with something that looks promising.

First, create and maintain 2 sorted data structures (e.g. search trees) containing all horizontal and all vertical indices that have at least one non-empty cell.

For this table:

```
 ABCDE
1
2*
3 %  #
4
5   $
```

You'd have:

1. A,B,D,E - used horizontal indices
2. 2,3,5 - used vertical indices

Store those A,B,D,E,2,3,5 index values inside some kind of a node in the 2 aforementioned structures such that you can link something to it knowing the node's address in memory (again, a tree node fits perfectly).

In each cell (non-empty) have a pair of links to the index nodes describing its location (I'm using & to denote a link/reference to a node):

- *: &2,&A
- %: &3,&B
- #: &3,&E
- $: &5,&D

This is sufficient to define a table.

Now, how do we handle row/column insertion? We insert the new row/column index into the respective (horizontal or vertical) index data structure and update the index values after it (=to the right or below). Then we add new cells for this new row/column (if any) and link them to the appropriate index nodes.

For example, let's insert a row between rows 3 and 4 and add a cell with @ in it at 4C (in the new row):

```
 ABCDE
1
2*
3 %  #
4  @   <- new row 4
5      <- used to be row 4
6   $  <- used to be row 5
```

Your index structures are now:

1. A,B,C(new),D,E - used horizontal indices
2. 2,3,4(new),6(used to be 5) - used vertical indices

The cells now link to the index nodes like this:

- *: &2,&A - same as before
- %: &3,&B - same as before
- #: &3,&E - same as before
- @: &4,&C - new cell linking to new index nodes 4 and C
- $: &6,&D - used to be &5,&D

But look at the $ cell. It still points to the same two physical nodes as before, it's just that the vertical/row node now contains index 6 instead of index 5.

If there were 100 cells nodes below the $ cell, say occupying only 5 non-empty rows, you'd need to update only 5 indices in the row/vertical index data structure, not 100.

You can delete rows and columns in a similar fashion.

Now, to make this all useful, you also need to be able to locate every cell by its coordinates.

For that you can create another sorted data structure (again, possibly a search tree), where every key is a combination of the addresses of the index nodes and the value is the location of cell data (or the cell data itself).

With that, if you want to get to cell 3B, you find the nodes for 3 and B in the index data structures, take their addresses &3 and &B, combine them into &3*2<sup>32</sup>+&B and use that as a key to locate the % cell in the 3rd data structure I've just defined. (Note: 2<sup>32</sup> is actually 2<sup>pointer size in bits</sup> and can vary from system to system.)

Whatever happens to other cells, the addresses &3 and &B in the %'s cell links will remain the same, even if the indices of the % cell change from 3B to something else.

You may develop iteration on top of this easily.

Merging should be feasible too, but I haven't focused on it.

Comment: Alexey, your idea sounds great! I'm going to try to implement it and test. After I finish, I will give you feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Alexey, sorry for delaying with feedback. Thanks a lot! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just storing Key Value pairs like you would in excel. For example think of your excel document has columns A - AA etc... and rows 1 - 256000...etc So just store the values that have date like in some type of key-value pairs.

For example:

```
someKeyValueStore = new KeyValueStore();

someData = new Cell(A1,"SomeValue");

someOtherData = new Cell(C2,"SomeOtherValue");

someKeyValueStore.AddKeyValuePair(someData);
someKeyValueStore.AddKeyValuePair(someOtherData);
```

In this case you don't have to care about empty cells at all. You just have access to the ones that are not empty.  Of course you probably would want to keep track of the keys in a collection so you could easily see if you had a value for a particular key or not. But that is essentially the simplest way to handle it.

Comment: Adam, thanks. Your idea is right! But I also need some ideas about the internal data structure implementation. The main issue is that when I use some sparse data structure, I have to store cell incides with the cell data. But when some row or column is inserted or updated, I have to update all indices of non-empty cells. Maybe there is some solution that will allow to avoid the necessity to update cell indices?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't finished writing the answer and accidentally posted it :( Now I have finished (edited) it